# How to do an action if an order is placed by a customer

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, customer, rwd

My module is when the order is placed by the customer, then automatically store some data(which are related to the product) into the custom table in database. what I want is how to detect the order placing moment. 
Help me...
I hope you guys will understand my question..

Thanks!..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 events you might use (there might be others).
`sales_order_place_before` is dispatched before the order is placed.
`sales_order_place_after` is dispatched after the order is placed.
You can create an observer for one of those events. You will [find here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) a tutorial on how to create observers.
You can access the order in your observer method like this:

```
public function doSomethingHere($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
}
```

Comment: why  down vote point. i cannot understand...

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you can achieve what you want using observers/events

In your module config.xml you can hook to an event like this:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <your_module_event_handler_name>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>methodName</method>
            </your_module_event_handler_name>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after> 
</events>
```

Then in the Models folder of your module create a file called Observer.php and add your method to handle the event:

```
public function methodName(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
}
```