# Magento 1.9 : What event used before order placed and get shipping information for the order

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

For my condition how to get the shipping methods before order placed

My Observer : https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Answer (score 3):

The event before placing order is “sales_order_place_before“

Answer (score 3):

[How to do an action if an order is placed by a customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/70644/72911)

You have 2 events you might use (there might be others).
`sales_order_place_before` is dispatched before the order is placed.
`sales_order_place_after` is dispatched after the order is placed.
You can create an observer for one of those events. You will [find here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) a tutorial on how to create observers.
You can access the order in your observer method like this:

```
public function doSomethingHere($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In magento1 try to do with this event `sales_order_place_before` which is work with before place order. and put in `config.xml`

```
<sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>   
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>gta_kolupadiRestrict/observer</class>
                    <method>cartevent</method>
                </Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
```

**hope its work for you**

Comment: My observer still not wokring -> https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Comment: check with this - $Observer->getEvent();

Comment: Not working, i need my shipping method without placing an order using observer, here in checkout page granted total generated using shipping method, but log not created

Comment: here is my updated gist https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Comment: can you please verify with https://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/events-and-observers-a-magento-tutorial/

Comment: i'm sure issue is comming from xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98222/discussion-between-zus-and-anas-mansuri).

Comment: have you checked which i send you url.

Comment: Yes, i checked.

Comment: what event used for checking shipping country?  @Anas Mansuri

Comment: what you mean ? can you explain in detail ?

Comment: sorry for late reply,,, One of my product should be order only in india, not for other country. So that how to check shipping county if shipping country is not india and should be shown message in shipping method area message like "This product [my products name] not for other countries"

Comment: Here is my gist https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Comment: you can try via jquery.

Comment: Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/301777/57334

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sales_order_place_before` event before placing the order.

Also, for getting shipping description for the order, you can use below code in your observer.

```
$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
echo $order->getShippingDescription();
```

If you want shipping method data, then you can use below code

```
$shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
var_dump($shipping->getData());
```

**Edit:**

I've changed `$Observer` to `$observer` in your Observer.php file. I think the issue is with the naming of the `observer` variable.

```
<?php
class Gta_KolupadiRestrict_Model_Observer {
    public function cartevent($observer) {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod();
            Mage::log($shipping->getName(),null,'event.log');
    }   
}
?>
```

**Hope it helps!!!**

Comment: My observer still not wokring -> https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Comment: Updated my answer, please have a review.

Comment: Just change your observer with above I've shared and try again.

Comment: Not working, i need my shipping method without placing an order using observer, here in checkout page granted total generated using shipping method, but log not created

Comment: here is my updated gist https://gist.github.com/ZusZus/66da0a7aaeb0db53eff38d8bb89ae941

Comment: Change $observer->getEvent(); to $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); to load order data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98220/discussion-between-zus-and-sumit).

Comment: Hello sumit, what event used for checking shipping country?