# Magento 1.9 - Anyone help me What is error in my Observer?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, debugging

My Custom observer :

**app\etc\modules\Gta_FindPaymentGateway.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Gta\FindPaymentGateway\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
    </modules>
    <global> 
        <models>
            <gta_findpaymentgateway>
                <class>Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model</class>
            </gta_findpaymentgateway>
        </models>   
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer>   
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>paymenter</method>
                    </Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_before>      
        </events>
    </global>   
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Gta\FindPaymentGateway\Model\Observer.php**

```
<?php
    class Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
    {
        public function paymenter($Observer)
        {
             $order = $Observer->getEvent();
             Mage::log($order->getName(),null,'event.log',true);
        }
    }
?>
```

log not created.

Share any debug tool for magento?

Comment: Your code is correct and working for me.

Comment: check your log is enabled

Comment: Yes, my log enabled, other observer log files generated at var/log location, this one only not generate log file.

Comment: instead, logging order object try to log some plain text

Comment: https://justpaste.it/69ng1 still not generate log file.

Comment: nothing seems wrong with code. please check module is enable OR put die in observer class .

Comment: @Pawan Yes, my module enabled, after added die nothing will happen. How to solve my issue? observer => https://justpaste.it/7l2ka

Comment: you added ```die``` after ```paymenter``` method. try to put ```die``` inside

Comment: I am sure that your observer is not getting executed. Please check if your event is getting fired and capturing data inside observer method

Comment: Make sure to set 777 permission on var/log/ folders in magento root

Comment: Check my answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302463/59677

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after creating the module ? Try refreshing cache

Comment: @Mohamed23gharbi Yes, i did, no response.

Comment: Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally done restart my wamp server and also clear & flush cache.

Answer (score 1):

I have created module same as yours, Please check the below code.

> app\code\local\Gta\FindPaymentGateway\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Gta_FindPaymentGateway>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <models>
      <findpaymentgateway>
        <class>Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>findpaymentgateway_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </findpaymentgateway>
    </models>
    <events>
      <sales_order_place_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <sales_order_place_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>findpaymentgateway/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>paymenter</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
            <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
          </sales_order_place_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </sales_order_place_before>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

> app\code\local\Gta\FindPaymentGateway\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
class Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
{

    public function paymenter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        Mage::log($event->getName(),null,'event.log');
    }

}
```

Logfile created in **var/log/event.log** and print the **sales_order_place_before**, check the below screenshot.

[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I need how to get what event i am using. Code :https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/301862/57334

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please check.

Comment: Same code what i post, still not generated log file.

Comment: Have you used the same code as I have posted in this answer for config.xml?

Comment: yes, using same code

Answer (score 1):

People report your code to work correctly on their installations, so the issue obviously is specific to your setup or magento project's code base.

https://justpaste.it/7l2ka proves that your observer class isn't being parsed as php would fail with a syntax error doing so. For magento backend development I rely on [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun). It provides all kind of useful commands you should make yourself familiar with.

For a start I'd make sure that your module and observers show up with `n98-magerun.phar config:dump modules` and `n98-magerun.phar dev:module:observer:list`.

Answer (score 1):

The observer code you shared in https://justpaste.it/7l2ka contains a **die()** which will break execution due to Fatal error (*unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT)*)

```
    <?php
class Gta_FindPaymentGateway_Model_Observer
{
public function paymenter($Observer)
{
$order = $Observer->getEvent();
Mage::log($order->getName(), null,'event.log',true);
}
die(); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!! IS THIS STILL IN YOUR CODE ??? If yes remove it
}
?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Kindly run php bin/magento setup:upgrade command and then php bin/magento s:s:d command then it should work fine. or you may refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52081048/magento-1-9-magelog-isnt-creating-the-log-files

Comment: My magento ver : 1.9.2.3

Comment: Not a Magento 2 problem